# django remove all products from a cart

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cart

I'm using [django-carton][1]

[1]: https://github.com/lazybird/django-carton to add cart functionality to my products app.  I have the ability to add and remove products to and from the cart, as well as show the cart contents.  I'm trying to work out how to empty the cart.

Here's the views.py:

```
def add(request):
    cart = Cart(request.session)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('id'))
    cart.add(product, price=product.price)
    return redirect('shopping-cart-show')


def remove(request):
    cart = Cart(request.session)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('id'))
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('shopping-cart-show')


def show(request):
    return render(request, 'shopping/show-cart.html')
```

...and here's how I'm displaying the products on the cart page:

```
 {% for item in cart.items %}
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="/{{item.product.id}}/">{{ item.product }}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p>{{ item.quantity }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p>${{ item.subtotal }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <a href="/shopping-cart/remove/?id={{ item.product.id }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-product">Remove</a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I've tried a few different ways to clear the cart. I assigned `{{cart.clear}}` to a button but this also clears the page on refresh, whereas I'm trying to clear the page on clicking the button only.  I was hoping to do this without Java Script but I'm struggling to find a way.  All help gratefully received.

**EDIT**:

Here's the urls.py in case it helps:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^add/$', views.add, name='shopping-cart-add'),
    url(r'^remove/$', views.remove, name='shopping-cart-remove'),
    url(r'^show/$', views.show, name='shopping-cart-show'),
]
```

Comment: The answer is on the GitHub page you linked to.

Comment: If you're referring to `cart.clear` I mentioned that doesn't work ...

Comment: It does work if you call it correctly in a view. In other words, you need a separate form that posts to a view that clears the cart.

Comment: Whomever down voted - the reason I am here is to learn - folks normally give direction and help ease me into the right direction - I'm not an expert and down voting like this is discouraging.  Tell me why you down voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment, this might not be the best way to achieve emptying the cart, but it works.  Here's the view:

```
def clear(request):
    cart = Cart(request.session)
    product = Product.objects.all()
    cart.clear()
    return redirect('shopping-cart-show')
```

I also added a url pattern for the view.  Like I said, it works.  Lemme know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove(request):
    cart = Cart(request.session)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('id'))
    if cart:
        cart.delete(product)
    else:
       cart = Cart(request.session)
       cart.save()
    return redirect('shopping-cart-show')
```

Comment: Python use method =>  delete()

Comment: This doesn't work.  I get the error `AttributeError: 'Cart' object has no attribute 'delete'`.  I've added urls.py to the question whilst I try to work out what's going on.  Removing a single product works with my code - I'm trying to empty the cart.

Comment: This might not be the best way to do it, but I created a view call "clear" - shown below.  It works ...but is it ok?

`def clear(request):
    cart = Cart(request.session)
    product = Product.objects.all()
    cart.clear()
    return redirect('shopping-cart-show')`